# How can I make the loop counter not be greater than the final value?

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

So sample loop:

```
do i=1,1
    print *,i
enddo
print *,i
```

gives me `2` as the final value of `i`. How can I set up Intel Fortran for Visual Studio on Windows to give me a final value of `1` for `i`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, because that's how DO works; it stops when the control variable exceeds the limit.

In general, in pretty much any language with a FOR/DO counting loop, you should only use the loop control variable inside the loop body, and treat it as undefined elsewhere, even if you can't actually limit its scope to the body.

In your case, I would use a different variable to keep track of the actual last value of i in any iteration:

```
lasti = 0
do i=1,1
   print *,i
   lasti = i
enddo
print *,lasti
```

Comment: Way back in the day, though, wasn't this possible without using a `lasti` variable?

Comment: Another way to get the value 1 less than the value of the *do-variable* after the loop has finished is, of course, to write something like `print *, i-1`.  Since the Fortran standard(s) define the semantics of *do-variables* I don't share the concern about using it outside the scope of the do statement.

Comment: "it stops when the control variable exceeds the limit." - this is NOT how `DO` loops work in Fortran. The number of iterations is statically determined during the loop initiation by the three parameters in _loop-control_ - see §8.1.4.4.1 of ISO/IEC 1539:1991 (a.k.a. Fortran 90).

Comment: NasserM.Abbasi: what other languages?  I only found Python and some implementations of Pascal (the behavior is technically undefined according to the latter's standard). Any language with C-style loops, which is a whole lot of modern languages, will print 2.  So does BASIC, though since BASIC was based on Fortran, that's not really surprising...

Comment: @soumya you can always just use `i-1` since that's guaranteed to be the last value in this case; of course, if your step value is not 1 then it's not so simple – the lcv may never be exactly endval-stepval.

@HristoIliev of course, the number of iterations is precomputed; your answer describes the formal spec well. But the way that value is computed and the state of the lcv on loop exit combine to make the behavior logically equivalent to testing the lcv at the top of each loop and skipping past the end of the loop when the lcv exceeds the target value.

Answer (score 9):

This has been the way that Fortran loops work for decades and you can't simply change this with a compiler option. The Fortran standard clearly states:

> 8.1.4.4.1 Loop initiation
>
> (2) The DO variable becomes defined with the value of the initial parameter *m<sub>1</sub>*.
>
> (3) The **iteration count** is established and is the value of the expression
> `MAX (INT ((m2 – m1 + m3) / m3), 0)`

Here *m<sub>1</sub>*, *m<sub>2</sub>* and *m<sub>3</sub>* are the three parameters in the *loop-control*: `[,] var = m1,m2[,m3]`, Given your example of `i=1,1` (*m<sub>3</sub>* is implicitly `1` if omitted) the iteration count is `MAX(INT((1-1+1)/1),0)` which evaluates to `1`, i.e. the loop should get executed once. `i` is initialised to `1` as per (2).

> 8.1.4.4.2 The execution cycle
>
> The **execution cycle** of a DO construct consists of the following steps performed in sequence repeatedly until termination:
>
> (1) The iteration count, if any, is tested. If the iteration count is zero, the loop terminates and the DO construct becomes inactive. If *loop-control* is `[ , ] WHILE (scalar-logical-expr)`, the *scalar-logicalexpr* is evaluated; if the value of this expression is false, the loop terminates and the DO construct becomes inactive. If, as a result, all of the DO constructs sharing the *do-term-shared-stmt* are inactive, the execution of all of these constructs is complete. However, if some of the DO constructs sharing the *do-term-shared-stmt* are active, execution continues with step (3) of the execution cycle of the active DO construct whose DO statement was most recently executed.

Fortran tests if the remaining **iteration count** is greater than zero, not if the DO variable is less than (greater than) the end value.

> (2) If the iteration count is nonzero, the range of the loop is executed.
>
> (3) The iteration count, if any, is decremented by one. The DO variable, if any, is incremented by the value of the incrementation parameter *m<sub>3</sub>*.

The DO variable is always incremented as an iteration of the loop is being executed. Thus after the first execution `i` becomes incremented by `1` which evaluates to `2`.

> Except for the incrementation of the DO variable that occurs in step (3), the DO variable must neither be redefined nor become undefined while the DO construct is active.
>
> 8.1.4.4.4 Loop termination
>
> When a DO construct becomes inactive, the DO-variable, if any, of the DO construct retains its last defined value.

The last defined value is `2`. Thus after the DO loop has ended, `i` is equal to `2`.

I've pulled the text out of ISO/IEC 1539:1991 (a.k.a. Fortran 90) but one can also find pretty much the same text in §11.10.3 of ISO/IEC 1539:1980 (a.k.a. ANSI X3J3/90.4 a.k.a. FORTRAN 77; sans the `WHILE` stuff which is not present in F77) as well as in §8.1.6.6 of ISO/IEC 1539-1:2010 (a.k.a. Fortran 2008).

Comment: Maybe it is interesting to bear in mind that in the case `do i=1,3 //
if (i==2) exit //
end do` the variable `i` will be `2` rather than `3`. (The slashes mean new lines)