# Weird results analysing a numeric array

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I've written the following program to find in an array the: largest & smallest value; number of +ve & -ve values; number of primes & perfect numbers; sum of squares, average, variance and standard deviation (the last two are familiar to those who know statistics).

My problem is, the outputs from sum of squares and onward are incorrect. Could you tell why? The program I've written is:

```
integer,dimension(10)::num

open(10,file='in.txt')
open(100,file='in-n.txt')
read(100,*)n
do i=1,n
read(10,*)num(i)
end do

l=1
do i=1,n
if(num(i)<=num(l))cycle
l=i
end do
lar=num(l)



l=1
do i=1,n
if(num(i)>=num(l))cycle
l=i
end do
sml=num(l)



k=0
do i=1,n
if(num(i)<0)cycle
k=k+1
end do
n_pos=k



k=0
do i=1,n
if(num(i)>0)cycle
k=k+1
end do
n_neg=k



j=0
do n=1,n
if(num(n)<=1)cycle
m=2
30 if(mod(num(n),m)==0)goto 60
m=m+1
if(m<=sqrt(real(num(n))))goto 30
j=j+1
60 end do
n_prm=j



j=0
do n=1,n
k=0
do i=1,num(n)
    if(mod(num(n),i)==0)k=k+i
end do

if(k==2*num(n))j=j+1
end do
n_per=j



sumsq=0.
do i=1,n
sumsq=sumsq+num(i)**2
end do
sum1=0.
do i=1,n
sum1=sum1+real(num(i))
end do
ave=sum1/float(n)
sum2=0.
do i=1,n
sum2=sum2+(num(i)-ave)**2
end do
var=sum2/float(n-1)
sd=sqrt(var)

write(*,80)lar,nint(sml),n_pos,n_neg,n_prm,n_per,sumsq,ave,var,sd
80 format(1x,'Largest value: ',t30,i2//&
1x,'Smallest value: ',t30,i2//&
1x,'# of positive numbers: ',t30,i2//&
1x,'# of negative numbers: ',t30,i2//&
1x,'# of primes: ',t30,i2//&
1x,'# of perfects: ',t30,i2//&
1x,'Sum of squares: ',t30,f10.5//&
1x,'Average: ',t30,f10.5//&
1x,'Variance: ',t30,f10.5//&
1x,'Standard deviation: ',t30,f10.5)


end
```

The output is:

```
Largest value:              20
Smallest value:             13
# of positive numbers:      10
# of negative numbers:       0
# of primes:                 5
# of perfects:               0
Sum of squares:             2731.00000
Average:                      14.58333
Variance:                     16.26515
Standard deviation:            4.03301
```

When I write the problematic portion of the program separately in a different program, it works perfectly:

```
integer,dimension(10)::num

open(10,file='in.txt')
open(100,file='in-n.txt')

read(100,*)n
do i=1,n
    read(10,*)num(i)
end do
sumsq=0.
do i=1,n
    sumsq=sumsq+num(i)**2
end do
sum1=0.
do i=1,n
    sum1=sum1+num(i)
end do
ave=sum1/float(n)
sum2=0.
do i=1,n
    sum2=sum2+(num(i)-ave)**2
end do
var=sum2/float(n-1)
sd=sqrt(var)
print*,sumsq,ave,var,sd

end
```

Output:

```
2606.00000,            16.0000000,             5.11111116,           2.26077676
```

The elements of the array `num` are: 20,13,17,17,13,18,14,17,16,15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop

```
do n=1,n
  ...
end do
```

perhaps doesn't do what you think it does.  Well, it does, but it does more.

At the end of that loop `n` has (as there has been no early exit from the construct) a value one larger than it had before the loop.  You can find discussion of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11874421).  [I'd almost call this question a duplicate of that, but a little explanation is needed to get there.]

After that loop, your `n` no longer refers to the number of elements in `num`: your later loops hoping that `n` is this rely on a broken assumption.

You don't use this `n` looping idea in your fixed version.  You'll need to re-write the earlier parts with this fault.

Because in this example the number of elements you are analysing is equal to the size of the array, using compiler flags for bounds checking would help you identify this problem.  However, if `n` was originally not `10` but `8` (or smaller) you would merely have been referencing undefined parts of `num`: potentially a much harder problem to find.